# AttributeError with send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to open the link in new tab with this code:

```
great_per=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Know more Thoughts')
person_link=great_per.get_attribute("href")

person_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 't')
```

It shows an error as follows  when I try to find the object using `find_element` :

> 'unicode' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

And it shows the following error as well

> list object has no attribute 'send_keys'

So can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes, `get_attribute` returns the string value of an HTML attribute. What did you think calling `send_keys` on that would do? What are you _trying_ too do with it?

Comment: Did you try printing the value of `person_link`?

Comment: Similarly, `find_elements` returns a list of elements. Lists don't know how to `send_keys` either. And again, it's hard to guess what you might have been expecting that to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with finding the elements. You can only do send_keys only on a webElement. Here you are doing send_keys on a string(value/attribute) of an element.

```
person_link=great_per.get_attribute("href")
```

returns a value. Not a webElement.

If you want to send keys, you should do it on `great_per`. Because that is a webElement returned after `find_element_by_`

```
great_per=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Know more Thoughts')
person_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 't')
```

Answer (score 0):

To open the link in new tab you have to use the [ActionChains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) implementation and you can use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# code block
action = ActionChains(driver)
great_per = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Know more Thoughts")
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(great_per).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: DebanjanB I tried with ActionChains implementation as per your code, but it doesn't work for me. I doesn't show any error but nothing action to be performed after using this code block.

Comment: @MansiMehta Can you update the question with the relevant _HTML_ and your code trial for further analysis?